# Command to spam something discord-bot

Tags: discord.py, spam

so basically I am trying to make a spam command for my discord bot, which takes in a custom message to spam. Here's the code:

```py
@client.command(name='spam')
async def spam(ctx):
    global stop
    stop = 0
    content = ctx.message.content[11:]
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator or ctx.author.id in admins:
        if lock == 1:
            await ctx.send('Jesus bot is currently locked.')
        elif lock == 0: 
            await ctx.send('Beginning spam..')
            while not stop:
                await ctx.send(content)
    else: 
        await ctx.send('Sorry, but you do not have admin permissions in this server, or you are not a verified admin.')
```

For some reason, whenever I try to use this command, the bot doesn't respond. I'm not sure why this happens, and could use some help please.

Picture of bot not responding:

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

I have a spam command, but I only use it to mess around with my friends. I would not recommend using this as a public command, as you may get rate limited or banned for abuse or something like that. Anyway here is the code I have used for it.

```
  @commands.command()
  @commands.is_owner()
  # If you want to use admin only, use this below
  # @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
  async def spam(self, ctx, amount, *, word):
    int(amount)
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print(f"Starting to spam {word} in {ctx.guild.name}")
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}\nPlease note that this will clog up the bot's reaction time")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    count = 0
    counting=True
    while counting:
      await ctx.send(word)
      count = count + 1
      if count == amount:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await ctx.send("Spam complete")
        print(Fore.GREEN + "Spam complete")
        counting = False
```

At the top of your code, make sure you import asyncio as time.sleep will cause the whole bot to pause. Also the Fore.GREEN stuff is just colorama (import colorama).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) instead of asyncio. It is made for such repetetive operations and it is easier and nicer because it is made by discord and is included in `discord.ext`. Something like this:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@client.command(name='spam')
async def spam(ctx):
    #get message and do all the ifs that you have there
    spamLoop.start()

@client.command(name='stopSpam')
async def spamStop(ctx):
    # stop the loop
    spamLoop.cancel()

@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
    async def spamLoop():
        print("The message")
```

Comment: Note that you can only run the task once, you cannot run multiple instances of task, so it can only be used once at a time.

Comment: Technically you could define a list of messages and use only one loop for any amount of messages.

Comment: youd have to define the channel too

Comment: Of course but I didn't write whole code for him just gave an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Actually quite a simple way of adding spam

```
import asyncio


@bot.command(name='spam', help= "Spam to your heart's delight")
async def spam(ctx, thing, amount):
    count = 0
    while count < int(amount):
        await ctx.send(thing)
        count += 1
    if count < amount:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```